# rails, view does line feed for button_to but not link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, link-to, button-to

```
%p
  %br
  %span.footer_links
    = link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link)
    = link_to 'Edit', edit_link_path(@link)
    = button_to 'Delete', @link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
    = button_to 'Delete', @link, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete
    pppppp
```

Produces "edit" links on the same line but delete buttons on different lines, e.g.

```
      edit  edit
      delete
      delete
```

(two of each for emphasis about line breaks)

How can I get all the above on 1 line as in:

```
edit edit [delete] [delete]
```

I am doing this becuase I need to change my `link_to, :method => :delete` to `:button_to's`

Update: I added, `:class => '.btn'` to my button_to
with `.btn { display: inline; }` in my css but it hasn't helped.

```
<p>
<br/>
<span class="footer_links">
<a href="/links/354/edit">Edit</a>
 | 
</span>
</p>
<form method="post" action="/links/354" class="button_to">
<div>
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete"/>
<input class=".btn" data-confirm="Are you sure?" type="submit" value="Delete"/>
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="MvN6K03y5WcqSZRt4Au3zj+xsKhfZ9EEtkf2M7YCGhk="/>
</div>
</form>
<p/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, because both the `a` generated by `link_to` and the `input` generated by `button_to` should be inline elements.

This is exactly what CSS is for, though: keeping design details out of the HTML. So you could have CSS like this:

```
.footer_links a, .footer_links input {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

[Useful edit - also from Buck - You can use :form_class and then style the form and the div inside it as inline. ]

Comment: Oops, `button_to` actually [wraps the `input` in a `div`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to). Well, add a `:class => '.inline-button'` or somesuch to the `button_to` and style that? Please show the generated HTML if you need further advice.

Comment: but I can't stop it appearing :(

Comment: You can use `:form_class` and then style the form and the div inside it as inline.

Comment: Here's an answer for this question that did the trick for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240754/putting-button-to-inline-with-text-twitter-bootstrap-rails