# Putting button_to inline with text: twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view

I am rendering a partial with 2 buttons and text and trying to put that couple of buttons on the same line as my text, using twitter bootstrap. Partial file:

```
<div class="well pull-right inline">
<% if logged_in? %>
    Logged in as <%= session[:user] %>. <%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, :class => "btn btn-danger", :form_class => "form-inline form-horizontal" %>
<% else %>
    Welcome Guest! <%= button_to "Login", login_path, {:class => "btn btn-success inline", :form_class => "form-inline form-horizontal"} %>
    or <%= button_to 'Register', register_path, {:class => "btn btn-primary inline", :form_class => "form-inline form-horizontal"} %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Same goes for the logout button that renders when the user is logged in. I have tried putting various things in `button_to` class as well as its `form_class`, nothing worked so far, each button is on its own line. Any help or hints greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the `button_to` to `link_to` and double checking that css contains something like `position: relative; display: inline`. You might also check that the div is wide enough!

Answer (score 28):

You can access the style properties of the form created by the button_to helper using this syntax:

```
<%= button_to "Login", login_path, form: {style: 'display:inline-block;'}%>
```

Comment: This is missing an end quote?

Answer (score 8):

Rails generates a form with a div inside for `button_to`. To make it inline, you need to change both the form and the div to inline. In your css, add

```
.button_to,
.button_to div {
  display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If for any reason you cannot replace the `button_to` with a `link_to` the following approach worked for me:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;">
  <%= button_to "Text", action: "some_action" %>
</div>
```